# jQuery Firebug console output question

Tags: jquery

Here is the contradictory output printed by jQuery in the Firebug console, when I was doing some debugging on a page that did not behave the way I had intended:

```
>>> $("input.rtnBtn")
null
>>> $('rbtn_4')
<input id="rbtn_4" class="rtnBtn" type="submit" value="Rate" name="rate4">
```

as can be seen from the above, $("input.rtnBtn") is not finding anything - whilst the element with id 'rbtn_4' should clearly have been matched. Am I missing a trick here?

As an aside, although I am matching by class (because the id is generated at runtime), there is only one instance on the page - so I don't understand why jQuery can't match the element. Any ideas?

Comment: is it just me, or is jQuery temperamental? Sometimes it allows you to do really amazing things so effortlessly, and sometimes doing even the simplest things are fraught with unexpected behaviour - is that the nature of the jQuery beast - or is it just me?

Comment: do you mean `$('.rtnBtn')` or `$('#rbtn_4')` in the second case ?

Comment: @naiquevin: well spotted. Actually, thats even more maddening quirksome behavior. The correct selector should have been $('#rbtn_4') - but guess what, when I tried that, it returned null. When I tried $('rbtn_4')  - which was a typo, the element was correctly matched - whats going on?!

Comment: Try to create a jsfiddle.net version of the problem for us to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Firebug adds its own `$` function as an alias for `document.getElementById()` which is why `$('rbtn_4')` found the element with that ID. *(Why you need an element with the same class name as its ID is another question though...)*

Anyway, Firebug usually doesn't override jQuery, but it happens to me occasionally. The solution is to just use `jQuery(...)` in the console. You could also do `$ = jQuery`.

Comment: Hmm, strange but true. It seems you have to use jQuery instead of $ in the console otherwise the results may be unreliable.